# Black Seams When Rendering Normal Maps in Cycles

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, baking

as in the images appears: the first picture is the bake normal and rendered, and as you can see it appears some "seams" around it and with a low height, and in the high poly model you can see the height that it has, so what could be the problem? i ensure that the simple node setup its fine and correct setup.
[image]
[image]

this pictures shows the optimized model,baked normal, and node setup

[image]
[image]

this is how it looks all the high poly model details...

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's just a problem with the aliasing, Blender can't bake with anti-aliasing, you need to bake a  very large texture and downscale after to reduce aliasing, or try your bake with xnormal or other software

Comment: i dony get what you say, how i do that?